# How can an inner object reference its parent's objects at declaration?

Tags: javascript, scope

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dyncmuks/1/

```
var someObject = {

  run: function(str) {
    console.log("running");
    this.methods[str]();
  },

  method1: function() {

    console.log("method 1");
  },

  method2: function() {
    console.log("method 2");
  },


  methods: {

    one: this.method1,    //This == the 'methods' object
    two: this.method2     //I want to refer to the 'someObject' object

  }

};
```

Is there a way to make this work?

I could move the method declarations to inside the `methods` object, but that'll require some refactoring on the actual code I'm working on, and I just want to get this to work).

Comment: There is no way to reference properties of an object from inside its object initializer. The object does not really exist while the initializer is being evaluated.

Comment: [what are you trying to actually do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I have an object with a bunch of different 'main' methods. I need to put them into a list of key:values (key:functions) so that they can be iterated over for selection from a list.

Comment: Again though: why? That doesn't sound like a sensible delegation of responsibility, so in this case we're still at what are you trying to *do* rather than what code decisions did you already make. What does that "an object" do, what do the "main" methods do, why do you need them in a list, why do you need to iterate over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned, there is no way to reference to parent properties from a nested objects in object literal.
But I would suggest some alternative with *modular pattern*.
The following approach generates and returns the object `someObject` with a single public method `run`.
 The "main" object marked as private object and it can't be modified or be accessible by someone.(it's safe now).
 The `getMethods` method 'implicitly' returns the list(object) of all methods of 'main' object.

```
var someObject = (function(){

  var privateObj = {
      method1: function() {
        console.log("method 1");
      },
      method2: function() {
        console.log("method 2");
      },
      method3: function() {
        console.log("method 3");
      },
      getMethods : function(){
        var self = this;
        return {
            one: self.method1,
            two: self.method2,
            three: self.method3
        };
      }
  };

  return {
      run: function(str) {
          console.log("running");
          privateObj.getMethods()[str]();
      }
  };

}());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnbe510b/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if that's exactly what are you looking for, but I found out that you can achieve it using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

For example:

```js
var test = {
  someProperty: true,
  get somePropertyReference() {
    return this.someProperty;
  }
};

console.log(test.somePropertyReference);
```

Comment: So long as your support is for IE9+; there's no way to backport (polyfill) getters and setters for use in earlier browsers, even if you use the alternative method (no syntax changes) for defining them.

Answer (score 0):

You could by simply restructuring this a bit and using "bind" to bind "this" in the object constructor to the functions which should have reference to it.

```js
function someObject() {
  this.methods = {
    method1: function() {
      console.log(this);
      console.log("method 1");
    },
    method2: this.method2.bind(this)
  }
}

someObject.prototype.run = function(str) {
  console.log("running");
  this.methods[str]();
}

someObject.prototype.method2 = function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log("method 2");
}

var a = new someObject();

a.run("method1");
a.run("method2");
```